# url_to_postid doesn't work with the correct url

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

I've to extract the post_id of a product in my Wordpress site. 
I used the following code:

```
$actual_link = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

        $actual_link = substr($actual_link, 0, -19);
        //var_dump($actual_link);
        $post_id = url_to_postid( $actual_link );
var_dump($post_id);
```

`$actual_link` value is the following:

```
http://www.pecso.it/prodotto/741drinkflex-piatto-nondiv/
```

`$post_id` value is NULL. Why? Can you help me, please?

Comment: remove $actual_link = substr($actual_link, 0, -19); and check it will work.

Comment: thank's but I need post with $actual_link url..

Comment: Why are you `substr()` on `$actual_link`

Comment: because $actual_link contains a part that isn't not part of product page permalink

Answer (score -1):

current post id value is stored in global variables. please check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) of official documentation